# How to move UPSELL block on product page?

Tags: magento-1.9, up-sells, layout

All I want to do is moving the UPSELL block upwards on the Product Page so it will be displayed above the Reviews section.
I already can make it disappear just can't move it upwards whatever I do. 
I was trying to modify the local.xml file.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: give a screen shot

Answer (score 1):

in view.phtml you need found `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>` and then move

Answer (score 0):

you `don't need to do any code at local.xml`

Just call above below code above review blog at

```
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>
```

After:
If please add this code at local.xml

```
<catalog_product_view>
    <reference name="product.info">
        <block type="catalog/product_list_upsell" name="product.info.upsell" as="upsell_products" template="catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml">
            <action method="setColumnCount"><columns>6</columns></action>
            <action method="setItemLimit"><type>upsell</type><limit>6</limit></action>
        </block>
    </reference>
</catalog_product_view>
```

and  add   `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('upsell_products') ?>`  on view.phtml

Comment: Thanks for your answer Amit.

The problem is that I can't find this line in view.phtml

So where exactly I have to add this line, which file?
Sorry but I am still a novice to Magento :)